# Delphi TsqlConnection error password will expire

Tags: oracle, connection, warnings, connect

I have one problem with TSQLConnection component. I use it to connect Oracle SQL database, everything was good, but now I get that error " the password will expire within 7 days", I know this is SQL warnings, but when I use oracle session component for connect to database I did not get that error. Please help me, it is very important for me. My program must work :( I will wait you, thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better to add your connection string, and/or some of your code related to this connection here. Then others who know the topic can change your code to get the answer you are after. What Programming language you are using? Delphi? Then add it as a Tag also

Comment: I'm not familiar with Delphi, but I've seen the same problem happen with other programs.  The problem is that the password expiration "warning" is really an error, and the connecting program needs to know to ignore it.  With tools like SQL Developer, it required changing from the JDBC thin client to the smarter thick client - maybe Delphi has similar options?  (The thin client is just a .jar file, while the thick client requires a large Oracle client installation).  And of course another option is to change the password ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Delphi, but am very familiar with the reported error message."the password will expire within 7 days", is an ORA-28002.  If you only get that when connecting from MSSQL (via a linked server) but not when connecting directly to Oracle, then I'd be very confident that the oracle username defined with the linked server is NOT the same as you are using for a direct connection.  You need to show us the username that is used by the linked server, and then the output of (connected directly to oracle as a user with DBA credentials)

```
select username,
       account_status,
       to_char(lock_date,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as lock_date,
       to_char(expiry_date,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss) as expiry_date
from dba_users
where username='USER_IN_QUESTION';
```

obviously substituting your real user in question.

I've written about expiring passwords [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/exploring-password-lifetime-and-grace-period/): I'm pretty sure a lot of it will be applicable to your situation.